# How do i perform click() on existing data-element in PDFTron?

Tags: typescript, pdftron

Basically the scenario is, I have my custom button outside the viewer and i want to bind the functionality of, let's say "area measurement" to that custom button?

I want to bind the both highlighted button's in image i.e if i clicked "draw area" button,then both the highlighted buttons needs to be clicked.

TIP: kindly refer [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8cUj.png).

I have tried getTool() method but got error like `ERROR TypeError: tool.click is not a function`

> document.getElementById('items').onclick = function (e) {
>
> const tool = instance.docViewer.getTool('AnnotationCreateAreaMeasurement');
>
> tool.click();
>
> };

Please help me out of this. Is it possible to do ? if not then what's the work-around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vivek answer is the correct way to get the same behavior as the click event. Since the UI is using React, using `.click()` won't work because the button won't always exist on the DOM.

Also if you only want to set the tool mode without the header popup appearing, you can do something like the following

```
document.getElementById('items').onclick = function (e) {
  const tool = instance.docViewer.getTool('AnnotationCreateAreaMeasurement');
  // use the 'setToolMode' function on the 'docViewer' instead of the 'instance'
  instance.docViewer.setToolMode(tool);
};
```

Lastly you can use [getToolModeMap](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/CoreControls.DocumentViewer.html#getToolModeMap__anchor) to get a list of all the different tool modes

Comment: I think this is the efficient way to do it, thank you brother :)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by using `setToolMode(toolName)` method.

````
document.getElementById('items').onclick = function () {

        instance.setToolMode('AnnotationCreateAreaMeasurement');

};```
````